# Is there a way to add new Resources with Kustomize (as opposed to overlaying them)?

Tags: kubernetes, templating, kustomize

Using [`kubectl apply -k`](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/pages/app_management/apply.html#usage), you can overlay [Resource](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#resources) configs (that you have already defined). Can you create resources as well?

In my specific case I want to create a [local Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local) for the development environment. I do not have this Resource in the base folder though.

My folder structure is like this:

> ```
> ~/someApp
> ├── base
> │   ├── deployment.yaml
> │   ├── kustomization.yaml
> │   └── service.yaml
> └── overlays
>     ├── development
>     │   ├── cpu_count.yaml
>     │   ├── kustomization.yaml
>     │   ├── replica_count.yaml
>     │   └── volume.yaml <--- *Is this possible*?
>     └── production
>         ├── cpu_count.yaml
>         ├── kustomization.yaml
>         └── replica_count.yaml
> ```

Answer (score 14):

In your `overlays/development/kustomization.yaml` you can add:

```
resources:
  - volume.yaml
```